# Comment box (and comments) not displayed in WordPress Divi Theme

Tags: php, divi

I'm troubleshooting my client's WordPress (Divi) - the comments and comment box have been disappeared from all the posts.
I went through all WP missing comments troubleshooting steps (double checking comment settings, safe mode) but no joy.
I have checked single.php file and there's code as below

```
do_action( 'et_after_post' );
    if ( ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) && 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_postcomments', 'on' ) ) {
        comments_template( '', true );
    }
```

To the best of my knowledge this is what should give a comment box and display comments. Yet, when checking HTML source code of any page with a blog post the only thing related to comments is

```
<div class="jp-carousel-comments"></div>
```

and some more code related to JetPack carousel, none of the regular HTML related to comment box.

What other files do you suggest checking? Many thanks!

PS Comments are still visible in WP admin panel, just not on the the website.

I went through all WP missing comments troubleshooting steps (double checking comment settings, safe mode) but no joy.
I have checked single.php and comments.php - the code as above.
I have checked HTML source code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do they work in a standard WordPress theme (2022)? Are the comments added via the module in Divi? Are the posts governed by a theme builder template? Does it work in Safe Mode? Are they allowed at the post level? Website URL?